# Stuck with basic Javascript loops and Arrays in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an app as follows.

1. 4 countries where the user can travel
2. All 4 countries have distance specified.
3. User can pick up a bike from dropdown to travel to those countries .
4. Every bike has max no of units available and max distance they can travel.

Whenever the user selects a bike , it checks for 2 conditions:-

1. bike max distance >= country distance
2. no of bike units > 0.

If the condition fulfills the no of units get reduced and travelTime is calculated as shown below.

I got the app almost ready and working. There are few conditions in which the no of units for bike are not updating.

1. Counrty india - bike harley ( harley count becomes 1- right)
2. Country germany - bike harley ( harley count becomes 0 - right)
3. Country India - bike ducati ( ducati becomes 1,harley count becomes 1 - right)
4. Country germany - bike kawasaki (kawasaki becomes 1, harley becomes 1 - wrong (harley should be 2 again)

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-star-lxiy7?file=/src/Styling.js)

I will really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you have same bikes which are traveling in these countries then why you're handling bike data in each country object? Try to handle it separatly if possible, it might solves your problem :)

Comment: The reason for that being. The data structure is a nested array. Outer array has 4 countries and each inner array is a bike array.  For every country i need a dropdown which has 4 bikes (inner array).  I am sure there might be a easier way to structure the data but this is the best i can think of right now.